Number of Filters Guardrail limit reached when creating a Segment in Data Cloud
Scenario:
I was trying to add additional exclusion criteria to a segment but I was getting the following error ''Number of Filters Guardrail limit reached''. The segment has number of segments added as exclusion so if I add another one with single filter it works but if I start adding more filters from the attributes I'm getting this error.
From the Salesforce documentation I understand that I can have up to 100 attribute filters per segment split 50/50 between Include and Exclude. The segment I'm using has less than 50.
I would like to understand what causing this issue and what are the limits I'm hitting as it's not clear to me.
Does the Segment count the number of filters used within the additional Excluded Segment to make the total of 50 or an exclusion based on another segment is counted as 1?

In conclusion the count is based on the number of attributes-based filters added + the total number of inclusion filters from the nested segments (used as Inclusion or Exclusion). Any exclusion filters from the nested segments are ignored from the count if they are added to Inclusion or Exclusion.
Example:
Segment A:
10 x Inclusion filters + 5 Exclusion filters (based on attributes) = Total of 15 attributes used out of the total limit of 100 OR 10 inclusive attributes used out of 50 available(40 remain) and 5 exclusive attributes used out of 50 available(45 remain)
Segment B:
10 x Inclusion filters + Segment A added as Exclusion (count only the 10 Inclusion filters) + 20 additional filters (based on attributes) = Total of 40 attributes used out of the limit of 100 (60 remain) OR 10 inclusive attributes used out of 50 available(40 remain) and 30 exclusive attributes used out of 50 available (20 remain). Assuming those 20 you have added in exclusion criteria.
Current limitations are outlined here.
